# Segmentation fault when accessing a function I previously could access to

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, segmentation-fault

I am trying to acccess a function to check a condition, but although at first I could access to it, after several iterations I get a segmentation fault. I have included some WriteLogs to see what the return values of the function are.

This is what I get one of the four times I have been able to acces the function:

```
[Fri Jan 10 12:40:25:889]: [INFO][RouteInfoManager::UpdateRouteStatus] Driving Mode 2 passengers 0
[Fri Jan 10 12:40:25:889]: [INFO][RouteInfoManager::UpdateRouteStatus] IsAsva 1
[Fri Jan 10 12:40:26:060]: [INFO][DatasetParam::Int] DatasetParam_TypeException, setting speaker_gain
[Fri Jan 10 12:40:26:063]: [INFO][DatasetParam::Int] DatasetParam_TypeException, setting speaker_gain
[Fri Jan 10 12:40:26:175]: [INFO][DatasetParam::Str] DatasetParam_TypeException, setting cpu_version
```

And this, the segmentation fault error:

```
[Fri Jan 10 12:40:26:901]: [INFO][RouteInfoManager::UpdateRouteStatus] Driving Mode 2 passengers 0
[Thread 0xaa3ebb40 (LWP 27594) exited]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xa0f49b40 (LWP 27661)]
0x086d0273 in AlstomMP14::RouteInfoManager::UpdateRouteStatus (this=0x90889e8) at ../src/route/RouteInfoManager.cpp:283
283     WriteLog("[RouteInfoManager::UpdateRouteStatus] IsAsva %d", audioInfoProvider->IsAsvaAuthorisedInTrainCA());
```

These are the WriteLogs:

```
WriteLog("[RouteInfoManager::UpdateRouteStatus] Driving Mode %d passengers %d", trainDataProvider->GetDrivingMode(), trainDataProvider->GetDrivingMode() != DRIVING_MODE_AUTOMATIC
         || trainDataProvider->IsTrainWithoutPassengers());

WriteLog("[RouteInfoManager::UpdateRouteStatus] IsAsva %d", audioInfoProvider->IsAsvaAuthorisedInTrainCA());
```

And these the functions involved:

```
bool AudioManager::IsAsvaAuthorisedInTrainCA() {
    /// 1) Return true if train CA is without passengers and driving mode is automatic.
    return (!IsTrainCAWithoutPassengers() && trainDataProvider->GetDrivingMode() == DRIVING_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
}

bool AudioManager::IsTrainCAWithoutPassengers() {
    /// 1) Return true if driving mode is not automatic and train is without passengers.
    return (trainDataProvider->GetDrivingMode() != DRIVING_MODE_AUTOMATIC
            || trainDataProvider->IsTrainWithoutPassengers());
}
```

As you can see the WriteLogs show the return of the IsTrainCAWithoutPassengers() function, which is one of the conditions of the IsAsvaAuthorisedInTrainCA() function.

I don´t get why, depsite having the same value every time (2 and 0), sometimes I can access to IsAsvaAuthorisedInTrainCA() and some times I get the segmentation fault.

Comment: That is the reason why best practices recommend extensive unit testing against expected and unexpected inputs. And peer reviews to chase possible Undefined Behaviour invoking code. If it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, chances are that UB is invoked somewhere in your program...

Comment: Which line is 283?

Comment: @stark  this WriteLog  WriteLog("[RouteInfoManager::UpdateRouteStatus] IsAsva %d", audioInfoProvider->IsAsvaAuthorisedInTrainCA());  which calls to the IsAsvaAuthorisedInTrainCA() function

Comment: That line is not in the code you provided

Comment: @stark it is the second WriteLog I attached

Comment: Is audioInfoProvider a valid pointer?

Comment: @user253751 yes it is. It is defined as   `//> Initialize AudioManager
    audioManager_ = new AlstomMP14::AudioManager(ctrlManager_/*, intercomCtrlPrtclManager_, handsetCtrlPrtclManager_*/);
    AlstomMP14::audioInfoProvider = audioManager_; ` And whats more if it wasnt defined correctly it will never work, but it worked!

Comment: And did it get overwritten with some other value? You could try printing the value of the pointer when it works and when it doesn't work, and see if it changes.

Comment: @user253751 you were right! I printed the value of the pointer, and when it crashed its value was null, while when it worked it always pointed to the same address. What  could be that for?

Comment: @marpe Somewhere you wrote `audioInfoProvider = NULL;`? Or maybe you just didn't to set it at all? Also print when the pointer gets set, and then you will see whether it gets set or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
WriteLog("[RouteInfoManager::UpdateRouteStatus] IsAsva %d", audioInfoProvider->IsAsvaAuthorisedInTrainCA());
```

Assuming that `WriteLog` works like `printf` (or forwards to `printf`), your formatting specifier does not match the argument.

**`%d` is for `int`, not `bool`.**

Your program has undefined behaviour.

Stick in a cast to `int`.

Comment: While this is definitely a bug in your program, it's actually a guess that it's causing the segfault, because you did not present a [mcve] (or even more output from the debugger). For example, `audioInfoProvider` could be `nullptr`. Use your debugger to further investigate the crash.

Comment: Although %d is not for bool it works. And the point is that those WriteLogs I wrote were to see the returning value of the functions, but the error occurs whether I write the WriteLogs or not

Comment: @marpe It doesn't "works" it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @marpe _"the error occurs whether I write the WriteLogs or not"_ Then why are the WriteLogs in your [mcve]?